# Java: mouseClicked event not always firing

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener, changelistener

I have the following code to listen for mouseclicks, but it appears to not always fire.

```
nameList.addChangeListener( new MouseAdapter(){
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        nameListUpdated();
    }
} );
```

nameListUpdated() will run some of the times, but for whatever reason it seems that it will not run on every click like i want. Does anyone know why? Or is there more information to find the problem?

Comment: What is `nameList`?  (What class is it?)

Comment: Also, try overriding all the methods of `MouseAdapter` (or implement `MouseListener`) and `System.out.println(me)` each event.  Then you can see what event (if any) *is* called when `mouseClicked()` isn't

Comment: your question is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest instead of using method addChangeListener

```
 nameList.addChangeListener( new MouseAdapter(){
 @Override
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
     nameListUpdated();
 }
} );
```

use method for adding mouse listener [addMouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29)

```
 nameList.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter(){
 @Override
 public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
     nameListUpdated();
 }
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using mousePressed instead. It will fire an event when you press mousebutton without waiting until you release it. In most cases it does the trick.